# With a negative Constitution modifier, can you lose hit points when levelling up?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-advancement, hit-points

The PHB states that a wizard add 1d6 + constitution mod per level after first level. Would I subtract hit points when I level up if I have a negative constitution modifier and roll badly?

Comment: Hi DM Vegas! Welcome to the site. Please check out our [tour] to see how we work, and when you reach 20 rep, you'll be able to join us in [chat].

Answer (score 10):

Your hit points will never go down from leveling up.  You add 1d6 (or 4), and apply your Con modifier, but the minimum of that is 1, so even if your Con modifier is -3, and you roll a 2, you add 1 to your hit point maximum for leveling up.  I don't know if that has been clarified in the official errata, but at a minimum there's a Mearls tweet to that effect: https://twitter.com/mikemearls/status/582601826031132673

Comment: Do you have a quote from the rules or errata to back this up? It isn't mentioned in specific class descriptions, nor on page 15 of the PHB under 'beyond 1st level' (where hit points are covered)